# Float not iterable

Tags: arcpy, cursor, multipart

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/esripress/python/data"
fc = "Hawaii.shp"
   
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["OID@","SHAPE@"])  
for shape in cursor:  
        print "Total area: {}".format(shape.area)  
        partnum = 0  
        for part in shape:  
            pn = arcpy.Polygon(part)  
            print "Part: {} Area: {} Perimeter {}".format(partnum, pn.area, pn.length)
            partnum += 0
```

I'm trying to figure out how to print the perimeter and area of each individual island of the Hawaii multipart feature.  Initially, I kept receiving the error 'float not iterable'

However, after banging my head and changing the code over and over, I now receive a syntax error - invalid syntax  without specifying which part of the code contains the syntax error.  I think my error lies in the section of the code where I begin to iterate over the `for part in shape:`   What am I not seeing?  I know I can try adding a field and using the calculate field management tool, but I want to answer this question by reading the cursor.

Comment: print "Total area: {}".format(shape[1].area) then for part in shape[1]: you need to specify what field to use that contains the shape.. I think it's confusing to call your **row** shape. Shape is actually **row[1]** based on your cursor declaration. If you're creating a cursor like that don't forget to del cursor when you're done.

Comment: Personally I would MultipartToSinglepart your shapefile into a file geodatabase to see areas and perimeters as fields that you can run a simpler SearchCursor over to print out the same information.

Comment: Last line should be `partnum += 1` too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting the comments together:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/esripress/python/data"
fc = "Hawaii.shp"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["OID@","SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        shape = row[1] # shape is the 2nd value in the row
        print "Total area: {}".format(shape.area)  
        partnum = 0  
        for part in shape:  
            pn = arcpy.Polygon(part)  
            print "Part: {} Area: {} Perimeter {}".format(partnum, pn.area, pn.length)
            partnum += 1 # Increase by 1, well spotted by Marc Pfister
```

IMO the best way to declare an `arcpy.da` [cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001q000000) is using a `with` block, this handles the destruction of the cursor object automatically.. there's nothing wrong with declaring then destroying a cursor as you have done but if you forget to `del` your cursor (as you have done) a lock can be left on the featureclass which will cause problems later.

arcpy.da cursors iterate row tuples, not geometries, shapes are a value *in* the row for a spatial table that we call a feature class. To get the shape (geometry) for the row you can access by the index in the row. As you have specified `SHAPE@` the object at that index (1) is a [geometry object](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000070000000) which can be either point, multipoint, plolyline or polygon for a simple geometry type (not annotation, dimension etc), if you assume the shape is a polygon you can get the geometry area and perimeter properties as shown in the code.

For this example you *know* that the feature class is a polygon but for your reference you can test the shape.type (`if row[1].type.lower()=='polygon':`) before trying to access a property that will not exist for other geometry types; if you try to access shape.area for a point geometry type you will get an error *method does not exist* or something similar.